# Is it more efficient to use events when another class variable changes than accessing the variable directly? What about safety? What about properties?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm simplifying the situation as much as I can:

class 1:

```
public class GameFlowManager { 
    public float worldSpeed;
}
```

class 2:

```
public class Clouds {
    void MoveClouds(float worldSpeed){...}
```

I need to access `worldSpeed` from `Clouds`.
**Which way is more efficient?**

- Using `GameFlowManager gfm = FindObjectOfType<GameFlowManager>()`
  then accessing the variable by a pointer *(I know it's not really a
  pointer, but it's purpose is the same)*
  Like this: `gfm.worldSpeed`
- Or should I use an event, which calls a setter function in the
  classes that require `worldSpeed`? This way I wouldn't have to make
  the variable public.

Now this is only for unity, when I can't use properties. In a simple C# code I can use getters without any consequences, right?

Comment: *"Or should I use an event, which calls a setter function in the classes that require worldSpeed"* Can you update your question with an example of that too?

Comment: I'll just write it down there. I'd simply create `public event Action<float> worldSpeedUpdate`. I'd give the Clouds class a private worldSpeed and a setter (`void SetWorldSpeed(float newWorldSpeed) {...}`) for it, then subscribe the setter to the event: `FindObjectOfType<GameFlowManager>().worldSpeedUpdate += SetWorldSpeed`. And when I change the Clouds' worldSpeed I invoke the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With everything that ends in "Manager" (meaning there's likely to be one and only one of it), you should use the Singleton pattern, like this:

```
class GameFlowManager
{
    public static GameFlowManager Instance {get; private set;}

    public float worldSpeed{get; set;} // You could make the setter private to prevent other classes from modifying it if necessary

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this; // Note that this requires an object of type GameFlowManager to already exist in your scene. You could also handle the spawning of this object automatically to remove this requirement.
    }

    ...
}
```

And then, whenever you need values from this class, you do:

```
GameFlowManager.Instance.worldSpeed
```

This solution is perfectly optimal.

---

Edit: who said you can't use properties in unity?

Comment: Thanks, singleton looks great. But Unity is not great with properties, I had trouble with it, tho it was in version 4.x. The problem is mostly that I can't access a private property with getter from the editor. I like to have a consistent code, so I think it's better not to use them at all.

Comment: Unity requires public variables for editable fields, true, but that's just bad (or technically inevitable) design IMHO. Exposing public variables is the polar opposite of encapsulation. What I usually do is to create a private field with the SerializeField attribute applied, then create a public property to wrap my (safely private yet editable) variable. Best of both worlds for a few extra lines of code. You could of course use public variables as well, and it'd work, but it'd be against the official standards.

Comment: More on this (note the very first guideline): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057.aspx